# Teregram-error - TypeError: Object of type InlineKeyboardButton is not JSON serializabl

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have created a telegram bot when the user input '/start' it will appear 2 buttons which are 'Random Image' and 'Random Person'. The user has to click one of the buttons, then the bot will pop up a respective image, and following that, the bot will ask, "Did you like the image?" and finally appear two buttons, which are the "thumbs up" and "thumbs down" buttons. The user has to choose one of the buttons.

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
from requests import *

updater = Updater(token='')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

randomPeopleText = 'Random Person'
randomImageText = 'Random Image'

randomPeopleUrl = 'https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image'
randomImageUrl  = 'https://picsum.photos/400'

likes = 0
dislikes = 0

def startCommand(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    buttons = [[KeyboardButton('Random Image')],[KeyboardButton('Random Person')]]
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text='Welcome to my bot!',
                             reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(buttons))

def messageHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if randomPeopleText in update.message.text:
        image = get(randomPeopleUrl).content
    if randomImageText in update.message.text:
        image = get(randomImageUrl).content
    if image:
        context.bot.sendMediaGroup(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
                                   media=[InputMediaPhoto
                                   (image, caption='')])
        
        buttons = [
                [InlineKeyboardButton('like', callback_data='like'),
                InlineKeyboardButton('dislike', callback_data='dislike')]
                ]
        
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardButton(buttons), 
        text='Did you like the image?')
        
def queryHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query.data
    update.callback_query.answer()
    
    global likes, dislikes
    if 'like' in query:
        likes += 1
        
    if 'dislike' in query:
        dislike += 1
        
    print(f"likes => {likes} and dislikes => {dislikes}")
        
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', startCommand))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, messageHandler))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(queryHandler))

updater.start_polling()

When I have click the button for instance a random image the telegram will pop up a random image, but at the same time following error was incurred.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Learning App\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 557, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "D:\Learning App\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 199, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "d:\Learning App\chatbot\telegram_bot9(B)\main.py", line 37, in messageHandler
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
  File "D:\Learning App\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 133, in decorator
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Learning App\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 525, in send_message
    return self._message(  # type: ignore[return-value]
  File "D:\Learning App\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\extbot.py", line 202, in _message
    result = super()._message(
  File "D:\Learning App\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 339, in _message
    result = self._post(endpoint, data, timeout=timeout, api_kwargs=api_kwargs)
  File "D:\Learning App\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 298, in _post
    return self.request.post(
  File "D:\Learning App\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 364, in post
    body=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'),
  File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type InlineKeyboardButton is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `InlineKeyboardButton` where you should be using `InlineKeyboardMarkup`

In `messageHandler`, you should replace

```
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardButton(buttons),
```

With

```
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons),
```